# Flutter Dropdown default value

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a Dropdown filled with a Model

```
  List<PetKeyValue> _data = [
    PetKeyValue(key: 'Perrito', value: '1'),
    PetKeyValue(key: 'Gatito', value: '2'),
  ];


  DropdownButton<PetKeyValue>(
     hint: Text(_selectedType),
      isExpanded: true,
      items: _data.map((data) {
        return DropdownMenuItem<PetKeyValue>(
          value: data,
          child: Text(data.key),
        );
      }).toList(),
      onChanged: (PetKeyValue value) {
        _selectedType = value.key;
        setState(() {
        _selectedTypeId = value.value;
        });
      },
    ),
  ),
```

And the class model to fill is simply

```
class PetKeyValue {
   String key;
   String value;

   PetKeyValue({this.key, this.value});
}
```

All works fine, but I can't select a default value for my Dropdown

with

value: 'text' I have an error,

value only accepts a PetKeyValue() instance, but doesn't work neither

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign `value` to exisiting object from the list. Example:

```
List<PetKeyValue> _data = [
  PetKeyValue(key: 'Perrito', value: '1'),
  PetKeyValue(key: 'Gatito', value: '2'),
];

...

DropdownButton<PetKeyValue>(
  value: _data[0],
  hint: Text("Hello"),
  isExpanded: true,
  items: _data.map((data) {
    return DropdownMenuItem<PetKeyValue>(
             value: data,
             child: Text(data.key),
           );
  }).toList(),
  onChanged: (value) {
    log(value.value);
  },
),
```

`value: PetKeyValue(key: 'Gatito', value: '2'),` will fail because DropdownButton is checking if the value is in the list and it is using `==` operator and `PetKeyValue(key: 'Gatito', value: '2') == PetKeyValue(key: 'Gatito', value: '2')` is actually **false**.

Comment: Do you think this question deserves a downvote? every question I ask about flutter, receives -1 I don't understand why. :(

Comment: I think your question is fine, especially since documentation includes example https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DropdownButton-class.html that works because it's using Strings and not classes. Your problem required looking into Flutter source code. However people may see this question as too basic

Comment: I looked for 2 hours the answer and found nothing. I guess everyone is already very pro with flutter. Either way, thanks man.